# ParameterEncoding has no member JSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

Current Code is:

```
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
let encodedURLRequest = ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
let data = encodedURLRequest.HTTPBody!

Alamofire.upload(mutableURLRequest, data: data)...
```

The line `ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode` is failing when upgraded to Alamofire4 - please help - have been pulling my hair out for days.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [Alamofire documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#parameter-encoding):

`Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONEncoding instead of ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode

```
let encodedURLRequest = JSONEncoding(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

This saved my day :)